# fillrect not working in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html5-canvas, tetris

I'm trying to use a for loop to draw pieces for a tetris game.  I can't find a single tutorial or explanation that uses for loops with fillrect and fill style the way I'm using it.  I know how to get it to work with foreach, but for some reason it doesn't work in a for loop.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const T = {
    "first": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],

    "second": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],

    "third": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],

    "forth": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
}

var peice = T.first

function colorPeice(peice) {
    for(i = 0; i < peice.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < peice.length; j++) {
            if (peice[i][j] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillstyle = 'red';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1); 
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    colorPeice(peice);
} 

drawCanvas();
```

I know the values are getting seen at run time, but they aren't filling.

I've tried

```
function colorPeice(peice) {
    for(i = 0; i < peice.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < peice.length; j++) {
            if (peice[i][j] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillstyle = 'red';
                ctx.fillRect(j, i, 1, 1); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: use ctx.fill() to re fill the context, after ctx.fillRect(j, i, 1, 1)

Comment: You just can't see them because they are 1x1 pixel.. Try `ctx.fillRect(j*10, i*10, 10, 10);` 
You also have an error : `ctx.fillstyle = 'red';` you have to use fillStyle and not fillstyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (and see my comment on your post).

```
function colorPeice(peice) {
    for(i = 0; i < peice.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < peice.length; j++) {
            if (peice[i][j] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                ctx.fillRect(j*10, i*10, 10, 10); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, I feel so dumb.  That was it.  The little typo fillStyle, not fillstyle.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JenniferHightower You welcome it's a really "classic" error to make a mistake with the typo ! Can you just set my answer as the correct one? It can help people to find it when they have the same problem! Have fun with JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function colorPeice(peice) {
    for(i = 0; i < peice.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < peice[i].length; j++) {
            if (peice[i][j] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                ctx.fillRect(j*10, i*10, 10, 10); 
                console.log('fill', i*10, j*10)   
            }
        }
    }
    ctx.fill();
}
piece = [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2]]
colorPeice(piece)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px", width="500px">

</canvas>
```

Comment: Be careful about the `fillStyle`, you have to use an uppercase S.